# If A.B = C, given A,B,C are matrices, how do I calculate A from B and C using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, math

A, B and C are matrices.

`A*B = C`

Now I want to do a reverse i.e calculate A using B and C. How do I do it?
Matlab says that B should be a square matrices to calculate its inverse.

Comment: Do you mean `matrix`/`matrices` instead of `metric`/`metrics`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IF a unique solution exists, then one might best use pinv to find it. Using the example posed by schwarz...

```
A = [2 3 4];
B = [11 11 11; 12 12 12; 13 13 13];
C = A*B;

Ahat = C*pinv(B)
Ahat =
        2.788       3.0415       3.2949
```

The problem is, B is singular. So there are potentially infinitely many solutions.

```
B = magic(3)
B =
     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2
A = [2 3 4];
C = A*B
C =
    41    53    41

Ahat = C*pinv(B)
Ahat =
            2            3            4

Ahat = C/B
Ahat =
     2     3     4
```

See that pinv and slash both yield the same solution, since B is non-singular AND it is well conditioned.

But how about if we try something that is less well conditioned? In this next xample, I'll use a matrix that is not really that bad.

```
>> A = [2 3 4];
>> B = [1 1 1;1 2 3;2 3 4.00001]
B =
    1              1              1
    1              2              3
    2              3        4.00001
```

Well, it has a pretty large condition number, but this matrix is not what I'd call numerically singular.

```
cond(B)
ans =
           2865128.4655819

C = A*B
C =
                        13                        20                  27.00004
```

Lets try several different solutions now.

```
format long g
Ahat1 = C*pinv(B)
Ahat1 =
     2     3     4
```

pinv did quite well.

```
Ahat2 = C/B
Ahat2 =
          2.00000000017764          3.00000000017764          3.99999999982236

Ahat3 = C*inv(B)
Ahat3 =
          1.99999999953434          2.99999999953434          4.00000000046566
```

slash and inv were both not bad, although clearly worse in this case. The pinv solution seems a bit more stable for this problem.

We might as well throw a QR factorization at this too. Use a pivoted solution for the best stability. Note that when your system is nearly singular, we will still expect problems.

```
[Q,R,P] = qr(B);
```

You can see the problem by inspecting R. The last diagonal element is tiny compared to the remainder. This will cause problems in the solution, amplifying any noise.

```
R
R =
         -5.09902735824196         -2.35339392337313         -3.72620671848107
                         0         0.679365175314723         0.339681455393392
                         0                         0     -2.88675134520189e-06
```

The QR factors have the property that Q*R*P' = B. So we can solve for A here as:

```
Ahat4 = ((C*P)/R)*Q'
Ahat4 =
          2.00000000076851           3.0000000007685           3.9999999992315
```

Note that I've arranged the parens to be as efficient as possible, since MATLAB will use the property of R as a triangular matrix to simply do a backsolve. We don't want MATLAB to be factorizing a matrix that is already factored.

But now lets look at one posed by vahid:

```
Ahat5 = C*B'*(inv(B*B'))
Ahat5 =
              1.9970703125               2.998046875              4.0029296875
```

However, the solution posed by vahid was simply terrible. Do NOT use this last form. PLEASE. There is a reason why people tell you not to do so, or they should have told you that! Yes, I know there are a group of people who do not know the mathematics involved, and they keep spreading it. You may even find it in some uninformed textbooks.

The nice thing about pinv is it works for any matrix, singular or not. If a solution exists, it will find one. If the solution is unique, it will work. If the solution is not unique, then well, what do you expect?

Comment: Is there any advantage on using pinv over backslash operator?

Comment: @Andrey - well, pinv will probably be slightly more stable here, as I showed in my edit. I added a comparison for slash as well as a qr solution in the answer. An advantage of pinv is it will never complain, even on truly singular matrices. A disadvantage is pinv will be slower on larger problems.

Comment: I've tested your code and I am getting better results for backslash operator than pinv. I did show it in "format long g". What could it be? Here is my code snippet :  

B = magic(3);
A = [2 3 4];
C = A*B;

format long g;
disp(C/B);
disp(C*pinv(B));


I get [ 2     3     4] and [ 1.99999999999999   3.00000000000002          3.99999999999999]

Comment: The difference here is on the order of eps. TINY errors always exist in any floating point computation. Since you have chosen a matrix B (magic(3)) that has a condition number of 4.33, there is no expectation that these tiny errors won't be seen in the results. Note that the condition number of B in my example was 2.8e6, vastly larger than the case you tried, though still not singular. NEVER trust the least significant digits of ANY floating point computation.

Comment: @woodchips, will pinv work for finite fields as well? I am stuck with the same problem but am dealing now with galois fields. If A is not square, then whatever combination I try leads to a wrong result. Any combination of number for A gives A'*A or A*A' as singular. Is there any way to calculate pinv for finite field elements in matlab?

Comment: @schwarz - No. Pinv is not designed to solve the galois field problem. However, one can use row operations, essentially Gaussian elimination to solve that problem. And there is NO need to form A'*A. If a solution exists, direct elimination will work. Don't forget to use a multiplicative inverse instead of a divide.

Comment: @woodchips - I have only 1 row. A = [3 2], B = [1;3] and C = 2. If I have to find back B, how can Gaussian elimination help in this case?

Comment: @schwarz - You do understand what a (scalar) multiplicative inverse is? (If you don't, it is time to go back to your notes.) You also need to know that there is NO unique solution to that equation. This is true in any case of course. Write what that equation means down on paper. I won't do your homework.

Comment: @woodchips - I get your point ... just thought there would be some way to find an approximation like in case of pinv. Thanks!

Comment: @schwarz - why is any approximation needed at all? WRITE IT OUT! Your problem reduces to 3*x + 2*y = 2 mod p. Pick ANY value for x. Can you solve for y? Why would you need pinv here?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the backslash operator:

```
% if A*C = B
C = A\B
```

I don't think the solution in case of non-rectangular A is unique though...

Comment: The example I have,

`A = [2 3 4];
B = [11 11 11; 12 12 12; 13 13 13];
C = A*B; % = [110]`

So you mean one cannot find A in this case.

Answer (score -1):

First multiply two sides of `A*B=C` by `B'` (transpose of B):

```
A*B*B'=C*B'
```

Let `D=B*B'` (D is a square matrix):

```
A*D=C*B'
```

Now multiply two sides of above equation by `inv(D)`:

```
A*D*inv(D)=C*B'*inv(D)
```

`D*inv(D)=I`, so:

```
A=C*B'*inv(D)
```

Comment: Thanks Vahid! But the solution I get is not right first I obtain C from A and B and when I do reverse to obtain A, the A I get is different. For this case A comes out to be [16 0 8].

`A = [2 3 4]; B = [11 11 11; 12 12 12; 13 13 13]; C = A*B; % = [110]`

Comment: Ok I found the problem! Matrix was badly scaled or nearly singular!

Comment: No, no, no!!!!! If B is not square, then use a pseudo-inverse, like pinv. If no solution exists, then there was no solution. But doing this merely makes any condition problem worse.